# Proper way to maintain an SSE connection in Play

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, server-sent-events, eventsource

I would like to maintain an SSE pipeline in the front end of my Play 2.7.x application, which would listen indefinitely for some irregularly spaced events from server (possibly triggered by other users). I send the events via a simple Akka flow, like this:

```
Ok.chunked(mySource via EventSource.flow).as(ContentTypes.EVENT_STREAM)
```

However the connection is automatically closed by Play/Akka server. What would be the best course of action here:

- set play.server.http.idleTimeout to infinite (but [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/SettingsAkkaHttp)
  does not recommend it; also it would affect other non-SSE endpoints)?
- rely on browser to automatically reestablish the connection (but as far as I know not all browsers do it)?
- explicitly implement some reconnection logic in Javascript on the client?
- perhaps idleTimeout can be overridden locally for a specific action (I have not found a way though)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Periodically send an empty [`Event`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/api/scala/play/api/libs/EventSource$$Event.html) to keep the connection alive:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val heartbeat = Event("", None, None)

val sseSource =
  mySource
    .via(EventSource.flow)
    .keepAlive(1.second, () => heartbeat)

Ok.chunked(sseSource).as(ContentTypes.EVENT_STREAM)
```

[Akka HTTP's support for server-sent events](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.1.9/sse-support.html#server-side-usage-marshalling) demonstrates the same approach (Play internally uses Akka HTTP).